# Parsing a DateTime with ParseExact, what am I missing?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I'm trying to parse the following string to a DateTime:

"04-03-2008-16-18-08"

To simplify things I've written this unit test which always throws the exception "System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TemporaryDateTimeParseTest()
    {
        DateTime.ParseExact("04-03-2008-16-18-08", "dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm-ss", null);
    }
```

The format should be day-month-year-hour-minute-second (as should be evident from above). It seems right according to the MSDN description to me. What am I missing?

I have seen people say ParseExact is awkward, if this is the wrong method to use how can I use the regular Parse method to pick up this format?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `HH` for a 24-hour clock instead of `hh` for 12-hour clock.

[MSDN Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: Quick like a ninja, beat me.  +1

Answer (score 2):

You were using the 12-hour format for hour, not the 24-hour format.  Change your call to this:

`DateTime.ParseExact("04-03-2008-16-18-08", "dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm-ss", null);`